# Azure Application Insights JS integration failing with AI Exception

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

One of our application uses Application Insights and we observed following error being reported in the Application Insights, can someone help me understand how we can fix it:

AI: TelemetryInitializerFailed message:"One of telemetry initializers failed, telemetry item will not be sent: TypeError" props:"{exception:[object Error]{ stack: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'correlationKey' of undefined\n at https://xyzzzzzzzz.com/quote/generating:47:42\n at n._track (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:71156)\n at n.track (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:69930)\n at n.trackDependencyData (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:85929)\n at n.onAjaxComplete (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:46357)\n at XMLHttpRequest. (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:45057)', message: 'Cannot read property 'correlationKey' of undefined', name: 'TypeError'}"

Is this because of the AI Version used? seems like it is ai.0.js .. not sure what it means any help please?

Do you guys think this could be due the version of the JS above? I am confused as to why the JS Version is showing as  "ai.0.js:1.45057").

Our Custom Initializer Code
    `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';

```
@Injectable()
export class AppInsightService {

private appInsightConfig = (<any>window).environment && (<any>window).environment.appInsights || {};
private config: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IConfig = {
    instrumentationKey: this.appInsightConfig.instrumentationKey,
};;

constructor() {       
    if (!AppInsights.config && this.appInsightConfig.instrumentationKey) {            
        AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(this.config);
        AppInsights.queue.push(() => {
            AppInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(this.getCustomTelemetryInitializer());
        });
    }
}

logPageView(name?: string, url?: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any, duration?: number) {
    AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, properties, measurements, duration);
}

logEvent(name: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any) {
    AppInsights.trackEvent(name, properties, measurements);
}

logError(error: Error, properties?: any, measurements?: any) {
    AppInsights.trackException(error, null, properties, measurements);
}

private shouldSkipMetric(envelope :Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IEnvelope) {
    return this.appInsightConfig.trimKeepAlive && envelope.name === Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.RemoteDependencyData.envelopeType && /session\/keepalive/.test(envelope.data.baseData.name);
}

private getCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
    return (envelope: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IEnvelope) => {
        if (this.shouldSkipMetric(envelope)) {
            return false;
        }
        envelope.tags['ai.device.roleName'] = this.appInsightConfig.roleName;
    };
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This error means that one of your telemetry initializers is crashing and so it is dropping the telemetry as a result. `correlationKey` is not something the Application Insights JS SDK knows about, so it makes me think this is a telemetry initializer added by your application itself. Do you have any custom telemetry initializers? Adding one looks like this.


`appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(/* some function */)`

Comment: Thank you for your response so this means the issue is in custom Initilializer where we simply setting the CLOUD ROLENAME and that even if we are using old library it is ok or you suggest we upgrade to the new AI library. Cause I think my team is using old library atleast from the error it seems its ai.0.js.1 .  POSTED the Custom Initializer Code in Main Question Post above.